# Android onKeyLongPress

Tags: android, volume

I'm working on an android music player and want to skip tracks using long press volume keys.
I've found some implementations, but none of them worked as I want it.
I want to skip song on long press and change volume on short press (normal behavior).
In all tutorials/answers they handled long press with `onKeyDown` and `onKeyLongPress` but the short/normal press was only logged in `onKeyUp`.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "long pressed");
    switch(keyCode){
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        songNumber++;
        playSong(songs.get(songNumber));
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        songNumber--;
        playSong(songs.get(songNumber));
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode){
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        event.startTracking();
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        event.startTracking();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch(keyCode){
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

This is my code but with this I can only skip songs and short press has no effect. So I have only one volume level :(

I have no idea what to try now. Help is appreciated.
Thanks!

-v1r0x

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: my solution is the block below "EDIT".
How can I accept it? I'm new to stackoverflow

Comment: Simply cut & paste your solution from your question to an answer, there will be a large green check mark to click which accepts it. This way anyone searching for answers to a similar problem can see that this has been answered from outside the question. Also anyone who finds your answer useful can upvote it and give you some reputation points. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883383/android-onkeylongpress-when-webview-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution. Not the best, but it works.
`OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyLongPress` are still the same, but `OnKeyUp` is now this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(!event.isCanceled()){
        switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            audioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```