# Android onKeyLongPress when webview exists

Tags: android, webview, onkeydown

Regarding to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950215/onkeydown-and-onkeylongpress) and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493531/trying-to-catch-the-volume-onkeylongpress-not-working?lq=1) if you use onKeyDown and onKeyLongPress one need to use `event.startTracking();` inside onKeyDown. But I use WebViews.

What can I do to join onKeyDown and onKeyPress while not losing WebView's back function ?
I need this behaviour:
Inside webview,
* When user presses back button, webview will go back in history
* When user long presses back key, `finish()` will be called

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
         if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
             mWebView.goBack();
         } else {
             super.onBackPressed();
         }
         return true;
      }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the `onBackPressed()` method instead of `onKeyDown()`, which is called from `onKeyUp()` post-Eclair unless the target SDK is set to lower than Eclair. Returning `true` from `onKeyLongPress()` will cause the event to be cancelled, and `onBackPressed()` won't be called.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.isTracking()
            && !event.isCanceled() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Edit:** Actually you should override the `onKeyUp()` method instead to provide the same experience, and set a flag on the `onKeyLongPress()` call to check if it has been long pressed:

```
private boolean isBackKeyLongPressed;

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.isTracking()
            && !event.isCanceled()) {
        if (!isBackKeyLongPressed && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            onBackPressed();
        }
        isBackKeyLongPressed = false;
        return true;
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        isBackKeyLongPressed = false;
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && !event.isCanceled()) {
        isBackKeyLongPressed = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @trante: Did you override the `onKeyLongPress()` as shown in my edit?

Comment: @trante: Can you confirm that your `targetSdkVersion` is set to 5 or higher in your manifest. Otherwise the `onKeyLongPress()` method should be called. It's working for me on a Galaxy S2 device.

Comment: I checked your last edited. Works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11679788/2639515) answer.

Basically you use a handler in your `onTouchEvent` to detect a long press.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried. I added ```mySuperWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {```. This listener captures ```MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN```, ```MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE``` etc. But it doesn't capture back button press with ```MotionEvent.BUTTON_BACK```. So doesn't work.